# systemctl complains about no installation config, but it exists

Tags: centos, tomcat, systemctl

While following [this tutorial on installing tomcat on CentOS](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-tomcat-9-on-centos-7/) I came across a problem executing the line `sudo systemctl enable tomcat` - it complains with the following error message:

```
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
```

However, I clearly have an entry in my [Install] section:

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat 9 servlet container
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking

User=tomcat
Group=tomcat

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre"
Environment="JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.security.egd=file:///dev/urandom"

Environment="CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/latest"
Environment="CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/latest/temp/tomcat.pid"
Environment="CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms256M -Xmx512M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC"

ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/latest/bin/shutdown.sh

[INSTALL]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I get it to allow me to enable this service? I believe I've done everything right that it's asking for.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your systemd unit doesn't have an `[Install]` section. It does, however, have an `[INSTALL]` section. Section names are case sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

A similar warning (The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.) can also be seen on CentOS 7 (at least) when you've already enabled the service, and the symlink already exists in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/. I found this out when re-running `make install` from a Makefile intended for installing an app on a freshly provisioned droplet (VPS).

Comment: Just use `sudo systemctl status xxx` to have a check!